# Using .htaccess to redirect to website - 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

my .htaccess is looking like this right now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aid=(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1000)

<If "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'aid=001'">
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://m.example1.com/?  [L,R=302]
</If>
<ElseIf "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'aid=002'">
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://m.example2.com/? [L,R=302]
</ElseIf>
...
```

But when I access my website http://test.com/article-title?aid=001 with chrome now I get rediected too. Normaly I should only get redirected when using opera.

What did I do wrong ?

Update right now my htaccess is looking like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aid=(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1000)

<If "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'aid=001'">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://m.example1.com/?  [L,R=302]
</If>
<ElseIf "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'aid=002'">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://m.example2.com/? [L,R=302]
</ElseIf>
```

I tried this too

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aid=(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1000)

<If "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'aid=001'">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://m.example1.com/?  [L,R=302]
</If>
<ElseIf "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'aid=002'">
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example2.com/ [L,R=302]
</ElseIf>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END
```

Comment: Generally speaking, redirecting based on a specific browser or a version is a bad idea and you should avoid it. Could you share what is your case?

Comment: Well lets assume I want to redirect every one who comes to my website http://test.com/article-title?aid=001 with an iphone (so RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone) to another website of me http://iphone1.com/. Then I only want this to happen if the user is really using and iphone and I don't want it to happen if i browse my website with my chrome on dekstop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine conditions outside `if/elseif` conditions with what comes inside. Use it as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)aid=001(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example1.com/? [NE,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)aid=002(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example2.com/? [L,R=302]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END
```

Comment: Thank you I already tried that but then I get with chrome now when i access my site http://test.com/article-title?aid=001  --> Not Found

The requested URL /article-title was not found on this server.

Normaly it should then just show the normal page on chrome. Right?

Comment: This is just redirecting `http://test.com/article-title?aid=001` to `http://m.example1.com/` for user agent `opera`. So `/article-title` won't be there after redirection. Other than opera all other browsers won't be affected by this rule so `http://test.com/article-title?aid=001` will work normal way as without these rules.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought too but the website is not working normal on the other browsers now. Tried to access http://test.com/article-title?aid=001 with ie, chrome and firefox now and every time i get a Not Found.
When I access it with opera, i get redirected to http://m.example1.com/

Comment: `When I access it with opera, i get redirected to m.example1.com` That is what my suggested rule is doing and if that's happening it means my suggestion is working fine. Beyond that your 404 is some unrelated problem that you might still get even if you comment out these 8 lines shown in my answer.

Comment: The page is working fine with chrome ie firefox if those 8 lines are not in the htaccess. Thats why I don't understand the 404

Comment: The page i have is using wordpress it that the problem why I get a 404 maybe?

Comment: Yes definitely WP can cause problems. Try placing these rules above WP rules. Better you show your current .htaccess in question.

Comment: Wow anubhava! It is working. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After your explanation, I think you can find your answer at this website [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)